# jQuery ignores response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi anyone sees why my alert won't work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitForm(method) {
        var login = document.form.login.value;
        var password = document.form.password.value;
        $.post("backend.php", { 
            login: login, 
            password: password, 
            method: method},
            function(data){
            alert(data.message); 
            console.log(data.refresh); 
        }, "json");
    }
</script>
```

Response from backend.php is

```
backend{"message":"Log in credentials are not correct","refresh":"false"}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(arguments)` tell you?

Comment: ignore that, out of frustration I cut and pasted the example from the jquery samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is 'backend' at the start of your response?  I would start by removing that.  Everything from { to } looks good.

Comment: backend.php is the target of the post, it also sends back the response

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I have no idea where that is coming from (though you ment in the script, not the response)

Comment: I meant... why does it appear before the { in your response...?  It doesn't look like you're passing back a valid JSON object declaration.

Answer (score 0):

While I dont think its your problem, the callback function does take a 2nd parameter (the jQuery docs call it "textStatus") which is a textual representation of the HTTP status. Specify a 2nd argument to your callback.

```
function(data, textStatus) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Great_llama was right, for some reason I had a 'backend' echoed further up the script. Removed this and all go.